# I want to run independant simulations with openmp where only one parameter change each time

Tags: fortran, openmp

I run simulations with allocated array, and I want to use open mp to run a simulation with each of my 4 threads. Every variables should be private since I there is only one parameter that change between each simulations.

I call my parameters with ascii reading, all my array are allocated. Here's my main where I call the subroutines :

```
!--------------------------------------------------
                   PROGRAM SLO
!--------------------------------------------------
USE DECLARATIONS
USE WRITING
USE INITIAL_CONDITIONS 
USE COMPUTATIONS
!--------------------------------------------------
                  IMPLICIT NONE
!--------------------------------------------------
CALL INPUT_PARAM()

!--------------------------------------------------
IF (RUN_LOG) THEN
ALLOCATE(RUN_ARRAY(NB_RUN))

IF (LIN_LOG) THEN
DRUN = (RUN_MAX-RUN_MIN) / NB_RUN
RUN_ARRAY = RUN_MIN + DRUN * (/(ITE_RUN,ITE_RUN=1,NB_RUN)/)
ELSE 
CALL LOGSPACE(RUN_MIN,RUN_MAX,NB_RUN,RUN_ARRAY)
ENDIF
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(PRIVATE)
DO ITE_RUN=1,NB_RUN
IF (RO_EK) THEN
R_O = RUN_ARRAY(ITE_RUN)
ELSE 
EK = RUN_ARRAY(ITE_RUN)
ENDIF
WRITE(*,"('-------',I3,'/',I3,' RUN WITH COEF = ',1pE12.4)") ITE_RUN,NB_RUN,RUN_ARRAY(ITE_RUN)
CALL COMPUTE_SYS_PARAM()
CALL INIT_FILES()
CALL INIT_SYS()
CALL EVOLUTION_MHD_RUN()
CALL CLOSE_FLOW()
CALL CLOSE_ARRAY()
ENDDO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
ENDIF
!--------------------------------------------------
!--------------------------------------------------
IF (.NOT.RUN_LOG) THEN
IF (MHD) THEN
CALL COMPUTE_SYS_PARAM()
CALL INIT_FILES()
CALL INIT_SYS()
CALL EVOLUTION_MHD()
CALL CLOSE_FLOW()
CALL CLOSE_ARRAY()
ELSE
CALL COMPUTE_SYS_PARAM()
CALL INIT_FILES()
CALL INIT_SYS()
CALL EVOLUTION_HYDRO()
CALL CLOSE_FLOW()
CALL CLOSE_ARRAY()
ENDIF
ENDIF
!--------------------------------------------------
                END PROGRAM SLO
!--------------------------------------------------
```

Written like that, the compiler doesn't bother me but only one thread is working, I don't get whats wrong.

Thanks you

Seems like the 3 lines of openmp directives aren't there, because the compiler works, but nothing changes between this main and a main where everything is running on the master thread.

Comment: How do you compile? Have you set the proper compiler option to enable OpenMP (e.g. `-fopenmp` with gfortran or ifort) ?

Comment: Apart from that: 1) please indent the code, it's unreadable... 2) all private variables are unitialized once in the parallel region: you may want to use `firstprivate` for some of them.

Comment: Why do you need OpenMP for this? It's much simpler just to start 4 independent copies of the executable. If using a batch scheduler look into something like "job arrays"

Comment: Pieru, thanks for you answer, I just don't get how works firstprivate?

Comment: It works much alike `private`, except that all the private copies are initialized with the value the variable has just before entering the parallel region.

Comment: I would not really use OpenMP for this kind of task.